# How to change the value of the property target in the map object

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, openlayers

i would like to know how to set value fot a the target property of the map.
in the below posted code,i would like to change the target property to, for example to mapTest instead of map. to achieve that, i did the following:

```
#mapTest {
    width: 800px;
    height: 550px;
  }
</style>
    <div id="mapTest"></div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
```

and changed the target as follows accordingly:

```
    target: 'mapTest',
```

but then the code does not display anything
please let me know how to change the target property of the map object correctly

**app.component.html**:

```
    <div class="MousePosition">
  <div id="mouse-position"></div>
</div>
<form>
  <label for="projection">Projection </label>
  <select id="projection">
    <option value="EPSG:4326">EPSG:4326</option>
    <option value="EPSG:3857">EPSG:3857</option>
  </select>
  <label for="precision">Precision</label>
  <input id="precision" type="number" min="0" max="12" value="4"/>
</form>
<style>
  #map {//<---i want to change this
    width: 800px;
    height: 550px;
  }
</style>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
ngOnInit() {
this. map = new Map({
controls: defaultControls().extend([mousePositionControl]),
target: 'map',//<---i want to change this
layers: [
  new TileLayer({
    source: new XYZSource({
      url: 'http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg'
    })
  })
],
view: new View({
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 0
})
});
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm not sure what the exact problem is but here are some pointers, `Map` class has a method `setTarget` where you can change the target property but you also need to trigger `render` method as well so it will render the map in a new element container, it should look something like this:

```
onSomeEvent() {
    this.map.setTarget('mapTest');
    this.map.render();
}
```

On a sidenote, there is a whitespace in `this. map` between a dot and map, hope that's not in your actual code.